# Arguments from Controller passed to View was not fetched in php

Tags: php, mysql, yii

Im Using

> PHP language , yii-1.1.13 framework and MySQL DB.

Views code of Main Page.

```
 <?php
/**
 * The view for the trip schedules page.
 * @uses ManageTripSchedulesForm        $model
 * @uses VoyageServiceClassInfo         $voyageServiceClassInfo
 * @uses LocationInfo                   $locationInfo
 * @uses PierInfo                       $pierInfo
 * @uses VesselInfo                     $vesselInfo
 * @uses ServiceClassInfo               $serviceClassInfo
 * @uses FareSetInfo                    $fareSetInfo
 * @uses SearchTripsForm                $searchTripsForm
 * @uses FerryOperatorInfo              $ferryOperatorInfo
 * @uses ManageTripSchedulesFilterForm  $filterForm
 */

    $this->setPageTitle(SystemConstants::SITE_NAME . ' - Trip Schedules');

    $baseUrl = Yii::app()->getBaseUrl();
    $cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();

    // --- POS_HEAD
    // a plug-in used in manageTripSchedules.js
    $cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl . '/js/jquery.blockUI.js', CClientScript::POS_HEAD);

    // for this view
    $cs->registerCssFile($baseUrl . '/css/manageTripSchedules.css');
    $cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl . '/js/manageTripSchedules.js', CClientScript::POS_HEAD);


    $this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');

    /**
     * Maintenance Dialog widget
     */
    $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog',array(
        'id'=>'dialog',
        'options' => array(
                'title' => 'Trip Schedules',
                'autoOpen' => false,
                'modal' => true,
                'resizable' => false,
                'width' => 600,
                'dialogClass' => 'tripschedules-dialog-class',
                'show'=>array(
                        'effect'=>'drop',
                        'duration'=>500,
                ),
                'hide'=>array(
                        'effect'=>'drop',
                        'duration'=>500,
                ),
        ),

    ));

    /**
     * Render the maintenance dialog view.
     */
    echo $this->renderPartial('manageTripSchedulesDialog', array(
            'model' => $model,
            'ferryOperatorInfo' => $ferryOperatorInfo,
            'locationInfo' => $locationInfo,
            'pierInfo' => $pierInfo,
            'vesselInfo' => $vesselInfo,
            'serviceClassInfo' => $serviceClassInfo,
            'fareSetInfo' => $fareSetInfo
    ));

    $this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');

    <div id="grid-container" class="grid-div">
    <?php
        $pageSize = 10;
        $helper = new TripSchedulesGridHelper($this);
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
            'id' => 'tripschedules-grid',
            'dataProvider' => $voyageServiceClassInfo->searchTripSchedules(Yii::app()->user->ferry_operator_id, $filterForm, $pageSize),
            'emptyText' => 'No data found.',
            'selectableRows' => 0,
            'template' => '{items}{pager}',     // to remove summary header
            'pager' => array(
                'header' => '',                 // to remove 'Go to page:'
            ),
            'cssFile' => $baseUrl . '/css/manageTripSchedulesGrid.css',
            'columns' => array(
                array(
                        'name' => 'id',
                        'value' => '$data->voyage_service_class_id',
                        'headerHtmlOptions' => array('style' => 'display:none'),
                        'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'display:none'),
                ),
                'voyage.ferry_operator.name::Operator',
                array(
                        'name' => 'Origin',
                        'value' => array($helper, 'formatOriginTerminal'),
                ),
                array(
                        'name' => 'Destination',
                        'value' => array($helper, 'formatDestinationTerminal'),
                ),
                array(
                        'name' => 'DepartureTime',
                        'header' => 'Departure',
                        'value' => array($helper, 'formatDepartureDate'),
                ),
                array(
                        'name' => 'ArrivalTime',
                        'header' => 'Arrival',
                        'value' => array($helper, 'formatArrivalDate'),
                ),
                array(
                        'name' => 'TripHrs',
                        'header' => 'Trip Hrs',
                        'value' => array($helper, 'formatTripDuration'),
                ),
                'voyage.vessel.name::Vessel',
                'service_class.name::Service Class',
                'fare_set.fare_type::Fare Set',
                array(
                        'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
                        'template'=>'{update}{delete1}',
                        'buttons'=>array(
                            'update' => array(
                                'label'=>'Edit',
                                'imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/gridview/update.png',
                                'url'=>'"#"',
                                'click'=>'function(){updateTripScheduleJs($(this).parent().parent().children(":nth-child(1)").text());}',
                            ),
                            'delete1' => array(
                                'label'=>'Delete',
                                'imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/gridview/delete.png',
                                'url'=>'"#"',
                                'click'=>'function(){deleteTripScheduleJs($(this).parent().parent().children(":nth-child(1)").text());}',
                            ),
                        ),
                ),
            ),
        ));
    ?>
</div>
```

Views code of Add/Edit Dialog.

```
 <?php
    echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'service_class_id',
    $serviceClassInfo->getAllServiceClassesForSelection2($model->ferry_operator_id,
    $this->_ferryOperatorId , true, 'Select class'),
    array(
    'id' => 'service_class_id',
    'class' => 'selectbox',
    'ajax' => array(
    'type'=>'POST',
    'url'=>CController::createUrl('loadFareSet'), 
    'update'=>'#fare_set_id', 
    'data'=>array('service_class_id'=>'js:this.value'),
        ))
    );
   ?>
```

In my Controller, below is my code.

```
 <?php

    class SiteController extends Controller
    {   

    public $_ferryOperatorId;

    public function actionRetrieveTripSchedule() {
            $voyageServiceClassInfo = new VoyageServiceClassInfo;

            if (isset($_POST['id']))
            {
                if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
                {
                    $voyageServiceClassInfo = VoyageServiceClassInfo::model()->with('voyage')->findByPk($_POST['id']);

                    if ($voyageServiceClassInfo != null)
                    {
                        $this->_ferryOperatorId = '3';

                        $_json = array(
                            array('name'=>'voyage_service_class_id', 'value'=>$voyageServiceClassInfo->voyage_service_class_id),
                            array('name'=>'ferry_operator_id', 'value'=>$voyageServiceClassInfo->voyage->ferry_operator_id),
                            array('name'=>'origin_location_id', 'value'=>$voyageServiceClassInfo->voyage->origin_location_id),
                            array('name'=>'origin_pier_id', 'value'=>$voyageServiceClassInfo->voyage->origin_pier_id),
                            array('name'=>'destination_location_id', 'value'=>$voyageServiceClassInfo->voyage->destination_location_id),
                            array('name'=>'destination_pier_id', 'value'=>$voyageServiceClassInfo->voyage->destination_pier_id),
                            array('name'=>'departure_date', 'value'=>$voyageServiceClassInfo->voyage->departure_date),
                            array('name'=>'departure_time', 'value'=>$voyageServiceClassInfo->voyage->departure_time),
                            array('name'=>'arrival_date', 'value'=>$voyageServiceClassInfo->voyage->arrival_date),
                            array('name'=>'arrival_time', 'value'=>$voyageServiceClassInfo->voyage->arrival_time),
                            array('name'=>'vessel_id', 'value'=>$voyageServiceClassInfo->voyage->vessel_id),
                            array('name'=>'service_class_id', 'value'=>$voyageServiceClassInfo->service_class_id),
                            array('name'=>'fare_set_id', 'value'=>$voyageServiceClassInfo->fare_set_id),
                            );

                            echo CJSON::encode(array(
                                            'status'=>'success',
                                            'messages'=>"Target data is retrieved normally.",
                                            'val'=>$_json,
                            ));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo CJSON::encode(array(
                                'status'=>'failure',
                                'messages'=>"Target data can not be retrieved from server.",
                                'val'=>$_json,
                        ));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Models code of Service class drop down lists.

```
public function getAllServiceClassesForSelection2(
            $operatorId = null, $operatorIdEdit = null, $addInstructionRow = false, $instruction = null)
    {
        $serviceClassArray = array();

        if ($addInstructionRow) {
            if ($instruction == null) {
                $instruction = 'Select a ServiceClass';
            }

            $serviceClassArray += array('' => $instruction);
        }

        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->select = 'service_class_id, name';
        if ($operatorId != null || $operatorId != '')
        {
            $criteria->condition = 'ferry_operator_id = ' . $operatorId;
        }
        if ($operatorIdEdit != null || $operatorIdEdit != '' && $model->operation_mode == AdminGeneralHelper::OPERATION_MODE_UPDATE)
        {
            $criteria->condition = 'ferry_operator_id = ' . $operatorIdEdit;
        }
        $criteria->order = 'name';

        $servceClassInfos = $this->findAll($criteria);


        foreach ($servceClassInfos as $servceClassInfo) {
            $serviceClassArray += array(
                    $servceClassInfo->service_class_id => $servceClassInfo->name,
            );
        }

        return $serviceClassArray;
    }
```

In my JS file, below is my code.

```
function updateTripScheduleJs(id) {
// Get target data via controller and set values to fields of dialog.
$.blockUI({
    message: "Loading data...",
});

$("#dialog-msg").html("");          // clear the message area of dialog
// Ajax request
$.ajax({
    url: 'retrieveTripSchedule',
    type: 'POST',
    datatype: 'json',
    data: $.parseJSON('{"id": '+id+'}'),
    timeout: 20000,
    beforeSend: function(){
    },
    success: function(data){
        $.unblockUI();
        var res = eval('(' + data + ')');
        if (res.status == 'success'){
            for (var idx in res.val){
                if (res.val[idx].name == 'departure_time' || res.val[idx].name == 'arrival_time'){
                    $('#'+res.val[idx].name).attr('value',formatAMPM(res.val[idx].value));
                } else {
                    $('#'+res.val[idx].name).attr('value',res.val[idx].value);
                }
            }
            $("#operation_mode").attr('value','U');         // Set update mode
            $(".submit-button").attr('value','Update Trip Schedule');   // Set submit button label
            $(".update-only-div").css('display','block');   // Show columns for update
            $(".create-only-div").css('display','none');    // Hide columns for update
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");

        } else {
            alert("Trip Schedule does not exist. It may be deleted by other user");
            $.fn.yiiGridView.update('tripschedules-grid');  // Refresh the list of service class.
        }

    },
    error: function(){
        $.unblockUI();
        alert("Ajax Communication Error. Please contact system administrator.");
    }
}
);
```

}

Below is the scenario:

1. I clicked the pencil icon, dialog will show. It will load all the
           details depend on the selected row. This is correct.
2. It will load all the details. This is correct.
3. No. of values in Drop down lists for service class is wrong.
4. My expected output of service class is only 4 (based on DB) but in actual, all service class was displayed.
5. I found out that `$this->_ferryOperatorId   = '3'` from controller that was used in views
   `($serviceClassInfo->getAllServiceClassesForSelection2($model->ferry_operator_id,
    $this->_ferryOperatorId , true, 'Select class'))`
   has no value. 
   In my models code, if the `ferryOperatorId = null`, it will display all the
   service class.

My question is what is the correct code for me to get the value of `$this->_ferryOperatorId` from controller
then used the value in views.
:(

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Not too familiar with yii, but in most MVCs the controller will hydrate variables used for views via `$this->someVar`, then the view can reference the value via `$someVar`, I suspect that you should not be referencing `$this-`> in your view. Try taking it out, and referencing just $ferryOperatorId.

Comment: Hi @Mike Purcell, I also tried $ferryOperatorId, but no value was fetched. :(

Comment: Try `$_ferryOperatorId`, otherwise I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes I already tried this $_ferryOperatorId, but error was displayed (Undefined variable: _ferryOperatorId ). :( Hi @Mike Purcell, Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Hi Everyone! Please help me to solve this.:(

Comment: Hi @Mike Purcell! Please help me to solve this. Thank you:)

Comment: Try changing `var $_ferryOperatorId` to `public $_ferryOperatorId`, and be sure to reference the variable in the layout as `$this->_ferryOperatorId`

Comment: Yes, it should be OK to reference $this->_ferryOperatorId in your view as $this points to your controller, but where is this variable being set. Where is your view being called from as is not covered in the code snippets above.

Comment: Hi @ChrisB, I putted the code in view where I have used this variable $this_ferryOperatorId. Here: $serviceClassInfo->getAllServiceClassesForSelection2($model->ferry_operator_id,
    $this->_ferryOperatorId , true, 'Select class').

Comment: Hi @Mike Purcell, I already tried your suggestion from var $_ferryOperatorId to public $_ferryOperatorId and used the variable $this->_ferryOperatorId in view but it still does not work. :( Please help me..:(

Comment: So, I would add some trace statements into your view just before the  echo $form->dropDownList and then also in your function getAllServiceClassesForSelection2 that returns the array to check that the _ferryOperatorId variable is being passed through OK.

Comment: Hi @ChrisB, the value of `$_ferryOperatorId` in `function getAllServiceClassesForSelection2` does not get the value from **Views**, and I found out that no value was fetched in **View**. So I really dont know why the **Views** code does not get the value from **Controller** side :( Please help me to solve this.

Comment: is it being set correctly in the controller?

Comment: Hi @ChrisB, yes it is correctly set in the **Controller** and I'm using the right variable in **Views**. The variable in **Controller** and **Views** I'm using are the same. Please help. :(

Comment: Can I see the full code? See my profile for contact info.

Comment: Hi @ChrisB, I think I have already putted the required code to be shown. May I know what specific part of code you want to be displayed? Thank you:)

Comment: No, where is the view being called from?

Comment: Hi @ChrisB! I updated the code. I have added the Views Code of Main Page. Having `'label'=>'Edit'` is the one I have clicked to proceed in Edit Mode. Please help. :(

Comment: Thanks, but where in the controller is the view rendered?

Comment: Hi @ChrisB! `public function actionRetrieveTripSchedule()` is the method I'm using to get the details of the selected row and display it in the Dialog. Please help :(

Comment: Hi, I still don;t see where you are calling the code that you have listed under "Views code of Add/Edit Dialog". Your `public function actionRetrieveTripSchedule()` returns a JSON array - it doesn't render the form. Where is this rendered from? This is where your problem lies. You think you have set your _ferryOperatorId before calling the form but you have set it before returning the JSON array which is not directly relevant

Comment: Hi @ChrisB, Sorry to not including the **JS** file code. Please see updated code. I have added the JS file code. Please help. :(

Comment: hello, still don't see anything that says `$this->render('_form', ...`

Comment: Hi @ChrisB! Updated the **Views** Code of Main Page. Code for rendering the dialog is now posted. Sorry for not including it before. Please help :(

Comment: Thx - so this view you just posted ... in the controller does it set  $_ferryOperatorId before rendering the view?

Comment: Hi @ChrisB! Yes I set the value of `$_ferryOperatorId` in **Controller**. But in **Views** I cannot get the value of it. May I know what is the correct code for that? Please help. :(

Comment: So I still need to see that post of the controller ...

Comment: Hi @ChrisB! Yes you can see the value of `$_ferryOperatorId` in my `Controller`'s code. It was already posted. Please help.

Comment: But that bit of code doesn't render the view and it's in that view that you are having problems.